# Как получить корректное значение курсора?

Tags: d3.js

Вот так я получаю корректные данные позиции курсора (не менял масштаб):

```
self.x = Math.round(x_scale.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]-50));
self.y = Math.round(y_scale.invert(d3.mouse(this)[1]-50));
```

Как получить корректные значения после увеличения/уменьшения масштаба изображения?

Comment: Сами разобрались, молодец, это полезно =)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, да)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let x_ = x_scale.invert(coordinate.x);
let y_ = y_scale.invert(coordinate.y);
```

Полный рабочий пример [тут](https://codepen.io/doox911/pen/VJwQxO).